# Cant add security group to launch template

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, terraform, firewall

I'm writing terraform infra and i have a problem with security groups for my launch template.

```
image_id = aws_ami_from_instance.name12.id
network_interfaces {
vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.name32.id]
associate_public_ip_address = true
subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.name1.id
delete_on_termination       = true 
}
```

---

```
> terraform apply                                                                          
Error: Unsupported                                                                           
  on LT.tf line 15, in resource "aws_launch_template" "LTforASG                                                                          
  15:     vpc_security_group_ids = aws_security_group.pub_SG.                                                                          
An argument named "vpc_security_group_ids" is not expected here.
```

And if i write it outside of "network_interface" block it gives error like:

```
Error: Error creating Auto Scaling Group: InvalidQueryParameter: Invalid launch template: When a network interface is provided, the security groups must be a part of it
        status code: 400, request id: 59d14734-6cde-4027-b245-f3269b7a8071
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per docs, for [network_interfaces](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template#network-interfaces) you should use `security_groups`, not `vpc_security_group_ids`:

```
network_interfaces {
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.name32.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.name1.id
  delete_on_termination       = true 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was reading docs but i guess i missed this moment. works fine. Have  a good day